# How to change color of some view in ForEach SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have to change background color of one of the views. By default they are gray.
It depends on given value. If given value is equal to one of the key value it has to change its background color. My problem is that it changes two views. How can I identify which view it should change?

```
let numbers = ["200": "299000", "100": "329000"]

@State var selected: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(numbers.sorted(by: <), id: \.key) { key, value in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(key)
                    Text(value)
                }
                .padding()
                .background(selected ? Color.red : Color.gray)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
        setValue(value: 150)
    }
    .onAppear {
        checkValue(value: 150)
    }
}

func setValue(value: Int) -> some View {
    Text("\(value)")
}

func checkValue(value: Int) {
    for price in numbers.keys {
        if value >= Int(price) ?? 0 {
            selected = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than have a `Bool` as your `@State` to determine the background colour, I've updated your code to store the dictionary `key`. In this case it will store the maximum key value that passes the `checkValue` test.

I've added a `Slider` to make it easier to test…

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let numbers = ["200": "299000", "100": "329000"]
    
    @State var selectedKey: String?
    @State var value: Float = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(numbers.sorted(by: <), id: \.key) { key, value in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(key)
                        Text(value)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(selectedKey == key ? Color.red : Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            setValue(value: Int(value))
            
            Slider(value: $value, in: 0...300)
                .onChange(of: value) { newValue in
                    checkValue(value: Int(newValue))
                }
                .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            checkValue(value: Int(value))
        }
    }
    
    func setValue(value: Int) -> some View {
        Text("\(value)")
    }
    
    func checkValue(value: Int) {
        for price in numbers.keys {
            if value >= Int(price) ?? 0 {
                selectedKey = price
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think I can change it like that. I used to change state only with flag.

Comment: Noticed if I set value to 200 then it changes two views. Should I select by index?

Comment: It changes two views because both would match the criteria `value >= Int(key)`, i.e. `value >= 200`

Comment: What can I do to make it select only one?

Comment: OK, my bad, I think I misunderstood your question. Please see my updated answer